# How to close Main window or application from ShowDialog window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

As per question. So I have a main window (MainForm) load when application start. Then in MainForm_load event it do showDialog another form (LoginForm.showDialog()).

What I struggling about is, how can if user close the LoginForm (the x sign in the top right corner) it close the application?
in LoginForm there is only one button labeled "Login"

Thx before for the answer :)

---

well I've been trying this

```
    private void frmLogin_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            Application.Exit();

        }
        else
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

but it's invalid operation exception on Application.Exit()

so what I want is the application exit only if I close this Login form using [x]close button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I shouldnt use the frmLogin_FormClosing event at the first.

I use frmLogin_FormClosed

```
    private void frmLogin_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            Application.Exit();

        }
    }
```

thanks for all the help and attention guys :)

Answer (score 2):

Do this in Program.cs, like this:

```
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        using (var login = new LoginForm()) {
            if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        }
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

Comment: I call Login.ShowDialog() in MainFrm_Load() m8, how about that..?

Comment: Remove that, no longer needed.

Comment: It's not work the way I want it m8 coz I want load the MainForm first. btw I change the question a bit.

Comment: Your new code cannot work, the application never got started so you can't exit it.  I fail to see the point of loading the main form first, your text speak doesn't help.

Comment: I'm found the solution thanks for ur attention m8, I really appreciate it :) sorry it's kinda hard to explain. I'll post the solution right away.